# Not able to delete in repeat method in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

'Remove Choice' is not working. Here are two functions `addNewChoice` and `removeChoice`. The `addNewChoice` is  working however `removeChoice` is not working. I don't know how to solve it. Here my code is below:

```
<?php $obj = 1;?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     var app = angular.module('shanidkvApp', []);
     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) 
     {
          $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
          $scope.addNewChoice = function() 
          {
               var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
               $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
          };

          $scope.removeChoice = function(index) 
          {
               var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
               $scope.choices.splice(index,1);
          };

    });   
</script>
<%--here is my html --%>
<div class="btn btn-primary"  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice()">Remove</div>
```

Comment: `index` is undefined in the function.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is remove last item in array you can simply use [`Array.prototype.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
$scope.removeChoice = function(){                 
    $scope.choices.pop();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should be using lastItem to delete and remove index parameter

```
 $scope.removeChoice = function() 
 {
    var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
    $scope.choices.splice(lastItem,1);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass index in your removeChoice function in ng-click. You need to pass index of item in this function -

```
<div class="btn btn-primary"  ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeChoice(index)">Remove</div>
```

You can get index from ng-repeat loop.

OR if you want to remove alway last item then you shouldn't need to pass index key in function. But you need to change in you function as below  -

```
$scope.removeChoice = function(index) 
        {
             var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
             $scope.choices.splice(lastItem,1);
        };
```

Comment: there is a `$index` in ng-repeat but no `index`

Comment: You can get index in ng-repeat as ng-repeat="(index, friend) in friends"

Comment: well you aren't showing that. If OP was to try using `index` as you have shown with no other modifications it wouldn't work

Comment: Please share your ng-repeat code here.So that i can understand your rendering way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
     var app = angular.module('shanidkvApp', []);
     app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) 
     {
          $scope.choices = [{id: 'choice1'}];
          $scope.addNewChoice = function() 
          {
               var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length+1;
               $scope.choices.push({'id':'choice'+newItemNo});
          };

          $scope.removeChoice = function() 
          {
            console.log($scope.choices);
               var lastItem = $scope.choices.length-1;
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem,1);
            console.log($scope.choices);
          };

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--here is my html -->
<body ng-app="shanidkvApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="btn btn-primary"  ng-click="removeChoice()">Remove</div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add</div>
  <p></p>
</body>
```